# replace second occurrence of comma with line break in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Trying to figure out what's the best way to insert a line break after the second comma in a string. Here's what I'm currently using and it works, but I would like to know if a regex would be better for this.

```js
var data = $('#test1').html();
var position = data.indexOf(",", data.indexOf(",") + 1);

String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, replacement) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + replacement + this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

var newstr = (data.replaceAt(position, "<br />"));

$('#result').html(newstr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test1">3131, abc street, ZZ, ZZ  128 376</span>
<br /><br />
<span id="result">###</span>
```

Comment: to get to the second comma you could use: `.*?,.*?,`, and replace with `$0<br/>`  https://regex101.com/r/DOBdGP/1/

Comment: Your current code seems to eat one occurrence of 'ZZ'.

Comment: @Herohtar you are right, not sure why..

Comment: 1 zz is probably enough

Comment: @Andrew ahah it's for Canadian address so I need both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^(.+?,.+?),\s*` or `^([^,]+,[^,]+),\s*` and substitute with `$1\n` or `$1<br>`.

```js
var str = '3131, abc street, ZZ, ZZ  128 376'

console.log(str.replace(/^(.+?,.+?),\s*/g,'$1\n'))
```